# Why is the destroy method redirecting incorrectly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on the destroy functionality for a small rails app.  Currently, when I click delete I get the following error:

```
No route matches [POST] "/note/1"
```

Here is the relevant controller method:

```
def destroy
  if Note.find(params[:id]).destroy
    redirect_to note_index_path, notice: 'Note deleted!'
  else
    redirect_to note_path, notice: 'Note failed to updated'
  end
end
```

Here is a link example:

```
<p><%= link_to 'Delete Note', { action: :destroy, id: @note.id }, method: :destroy, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></p>
```

Here are the routes:

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern              Controller#Action
note_index GET    /note(.:format)          note#index
           POST   /note(.:format)          note#create
  new_note GET    /note/new(.:format)      note#new
 edit_note GET    /note/:id/edit(.:format) note#edit
      note GET    /note/:id(.:format)      note#show
           PATCH  /note/:id(.:format)      note#update
           PUT    /note/:id(.:format)      note#update
           DELETE /note/:id(.:format)      note#destroy
      root GET    /                        note#index
```

Comment: Exactly why it says-there's no POST request for that route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to specify the `action` in the `link_to` helper when you make a `DESTROY` request, try just passing the resource, and specifying the `method` as `delete`:

```
<p><%= link_to 'Delete Note', @note, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></p>
```

The `@note` object will give you the `id`, also without having to specify it.

If you make your route wait for a param `id` like `/note/:id`, then Rails will take the `id` value for the object passed as the second parameter in your `link_to` in this case.

Comment: Would the method be destroy since that's what it's called in my controller?  I tried to follow the CRUD model.  Also, I had to configure jquery in my project to get the popup to work, but I'm not even sure which part of this uses jquery.

Comment: Making the method delete worked, but I don't understand what all changed.  Are you saying that `@note` is equivalent to `{ action: :destroy, id: @note.id }`?  Also, is the jquery part `method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }`?  How does it know to use my destroy method?

Comment: `action: :destroy` isn't needed if you specify the method as `delete`, this will add a `data-method="delete"` attribute to your generated `anchor` tag, this way it's not a GET request, but DELETE pointing to the url generated, maybe like `/notes/1` (`notes/:id`), this way it remains only `id: @note.id`, which can be simplified to just `@note`.